# Creating an EXE from python results in command prompt opening

Tags: pyqt5, pyinstaller

This is my first attempt with PyQT5 and pyinstaller. I am using a simple command to launch httpd.exe from a button click

The command I use is

```
os.system(cur_dir+"//htdocs//api//taskkill /f /im httpd.exe")
```

It starts apache web server minimized and works fine. Apache starts and there is no command prompt window opening. When I create the exe via pyinstaller, I get a command prompt window flash when I click on this button. Is there a way to prevent that command prompt window from opening? I am using pyinstaller --onefile --windowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **--noconsole** option to get rid of command prompt window.

> pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --noconsole